# Why does my function return only one item that matches the criteria?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am new to javascript and I am working on a coding challenge that requires you to build a function that takes an array of strings as an argument and returns all strings with four letters or characters. My function will return the first four-character item it finds, but then stops and will not return any more four-character items. The code is as follows:

```
function isFourLetters(arr) {
  for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length===4) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I stared at this for 10 minutes or so trying to see why the for-loop just stops once it reaches an array element with four characters, and for whatever reason I just cannot see it and it makes me think there is something about for-loops that I clearly don't understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: because you return as soon as you find one - look at using array `filter` method instead

Comment: Because you `return` as soon as you find the first match, and therefore the other array elements are not checked at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is returning the first match (string with 4 letters).

You need to store those matches into an array

```
function isFourLetters(arr) {
  for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length===4) {
      return arr[i]; // <--- Here your problem
    }
  }
}
```

An alternative is pushing the matches into an array:

```
function isFourLetters(arr) {
  var matcher = [];
  for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length===4) {
      matches.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return matches;
}
```

Or better, take a look at the function **[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**:

```
function isFourLetters(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(str) {
      return str.length === 4;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may declare a "tmpArr" and add 4-letter strings as the loop finds. then return the"tmpArr" at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you enter the if condition you do a return. The return breaks the function scope and returns only arr[i].
You should create a new array inside the function and then use the if to add elements on the returning array. Then, when the for loop ends you can return the whole new array.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I remember learning now that the return keyword causes any loop to stop running. I'm glad you pointed that out, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can user filter method in array.The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
var arr = ['1234','spray', 'limit',test', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = arr.filter(arrElement => arrElement.length === 4);

console.log(result);
```

// Result : [1234,test]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter